# How to Find an Equation of a Plane Containing Point Q and Perpendicular to Plane P

Tags: analytic-geometry

Given point $Q(1, 0, -1)$ and plane $P: 2x + 3y - 2z = 6$, how do I find an equation of a plane that contains point $Q$ and is perpendicular to plane $P$?

Comment: There exist infinity of such planes.

Comment: Well I just need one. I'm kinda stuck at finding the matrix from the plane which will be used for the cross multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Q(1,0,-1);\;P:2x + 3y - 2z = 6$

The equation of a plane is $\pi:ax+by+cz=d$

$\pi\perp P\to (2,3,-2)\cdot (a,b,c)=0\to 2a+3b-2c=0$

Furthermore $Q\in\pi\to a\cdot 1+b\cdot 0+(-1)\cdot c=d\to a-c=d$

Thus we have the system
$$
\begin{cases}
2a+3b-2c=0\\
a-c=d\\
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
a-c=-\frac{3b}{2}\\
a-c=d\\
\end{cases}
$$
the system has solutions only if $d=-\frac{3b}{2},\,c=a+\frac{3b}{2}$

$2 a x+2 b y+(2a+3 b) z+3 b=0$ for instance
$$2 x+2 y+5 z+3=0$$

Answer (score 0):

With $p = (x,y,z),\vec n_1 = (2,3,-2)$ we have

$$
P:2x+3y-2z=6\equiv p\cdot \vec n_1 = 6
$$

The orthogonal plane will accomplish

$$
\cases{
(p-Q)\cdot\vec n_2 = 0\\
\vec n_1\cdot \vec n_2 = 0\\
\|\vec n_2\| = 1
}
$$

so there are infinite planes ...

Answer (score 0):

Any plane satisfying the requirement can rotate around the line containing $Q(1,0,-1)$ and perpendicular to the plane $2x + 3y - 2z = 6$, while still satisfying the requirement.

So, let the plane cut the $x$-axis at $A(a,0,0)$ where $a$ serves as a parameter. Then, its normal vector is
$$\vec n=\vec{AQ}\times (2,3,-2)=(1-a,0,-1)\times (2,3,-2)=(3,-2a,3-3a)
$$

and the plane satisfying the requirement is
$\vec n\cdot(x-1, y, z+1)=0$.
Simply to obtain its equation parameterized with $a$
$$x-\frac{2a}3 y+(1-a)z=a$$